# Bundles not appearing after website publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, system.web.optimization

I'm still kind of new with ASP.NET MVC, so please excuse me if I'm missing something obvious. I recently just published a site through Visual Studio to our development server to see how everything was working. When I browse to the dev site, none of our styles or Javascript that were defined as bundles show up in our code.

Local test system rendered code:
[image: Working]

Development server rendered code:
[image: Not working]

As you can see between the two rendered source codes, there is no CSS being added to the published code. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us an example of the bundle definition that you specified in your Bundle.Config class and the code that you used in your view to   render this bundle.

Comment: Here is my BundleConfig.cs file: http://pastie.org/8333347  And as I said below, I'm using `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` and `@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")`.

Comment: That looks fine, I assume that you actually add the specific css files, for example .Include("~/Styles/SomeStyle.css"). As explained in my answer below you can also try to add BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; to your BundleConfig.cs class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following line to your BundleConfig.cs file

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

**Please note :** If you are using bootstrap for MVC you might also have to add this line of code to BootstrapBundleConfig.cs

Comment: I added that, but now my header looks like this, look at like 10 and 12: http://pastie.org/8333800

Comment: Can you show me one of your include statements from your BundleConfig.cs file for example .Include("~/Styles/SomeStyle.css")

Comment: Sorry had a look at your BundleConfig and it looks fine. I'm out of ideas

Comment: What is the version of MVC you are using?

Comment: ASP.NET 4, the latest version.